# Как отменить незакомиченные изменения?

Tags: git, откат

Мне нужно переключиться с ветки А на ветку Б, но не могу из-за  незакоммиченых изменений в ветке А, эти изменения мне вносить в проект не нужно. Я хочу оставить все как было в предыдущем коммите.
Т.е. по сути нужно отменить незакоммиченные изменения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно положить в `stash`. 
`git stash push 'file_name_or_dir_goes_here'`.
Таким образом вы и не удаляете свои изменения, но и не коммитите их. И можно спокойно переключиться на другую ветку. Я так понимаю, именно это вам и нужно.
**UPD**
Просто отменить незакомиченные изменения: `git reset --hard`

Comment: @D-side Именно, спасибо, перепутал :)

Comment: Мне не нужно сохранять последние изменения, мне нужно их удалить (до состояния как было в предыдущем коммите) и перейти на другую ветку.

Comment: @Yiulia Дополнил ответ.